# Laravel 5 - session doesn't work when include a URL in PHP

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new in Laravel and PHP.

After I login successfully, the page redirects to index

Controller code as follow:

```
Session::save();
Redirect::to('index')
```

`index.php` code as follow:

```
include(URL('index/index_top'));
include(URL('index/top_banner'));
```

Here is the problem: session data is available in `index.php`, but unavailable in `index_top.php`. Page `index.php` display normal.

My English is poor, hope you can get my point.
Here, I just found that the sessionid was changed after `include()`, Why? How can I keep the sessionid.

**Attach:**
`routes.php` as follow:
`Route::group(['prefix' => 'index'], function()`
`{`
`Route::get('index_top','index\indexController@showIndexTop');`
`Route::get('top_banner','index\indexController@bannerShow');`
`...`
`}`

`top_banner.php` as follow:
`<div class="top_banner">`
`<?php` 
`if($resultcode == 0){`
`$i = 0;`
`foreach ($banner["body"] as $info) {`
`$i++;`
`if($i==1){`
`echo "<img src='";`
`echo( $info['adpic']);`
`echo "'style='width:1200px;height:145px'/>";`
`...`

Answer (score 2):

The problem are your **include** statements. Instead of including **local** views, meaning that PHP would be included and executed in the same context, you're including a **URL**, which means that a separate request will be sent and result of it's execution will be included. This request doesn't have any contextual information attached like cookies, that would help identify your session, **that's why session data is not available**.

Replace

```
include(URL('index/index_top'));
include(URL('index/top_banner'));
```

with

```
include('index/index_top.php'); //or whatever local path to index_top.php is
include('index/top_banner.php'); //or whatever local path to top_banner.php is
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But I need URL as a param. Because the file `index_top.php` is not a static page. Maybe you have other solution.

Comment: What do you mean "is not a static page"? The php in index_top.php will be executed with every request if that's your concern, so the result will be the same but you will have access to the session in index_top.php

Comment: Sorry！ I mean that at beginning the `index_top.php` has no data, so I need initiated a request to server to receive data.

Comment: Executing the index_top with or without calling URL directly DO EXACTLY THE SAME THING. the only diifference in this context is that you will or won't have access to session data.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you without using the URL please paste your index_top, as I'd need to see it to understand the issue.

Comment: Excuse If you have IM？If you have some time ? Thanks!

Comment: Please just update the question instead so that everyone can benefit